# Trying to upload file to remote machine getting exception " (530) Not logged in"

Tags: c#, file-upload, remote-server

I am trying to upload file to remote machine getting exception

> (530) Not logged in

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
string filePath = "D:/CLIENT/12345.txt";
webClient.UploadFile("ftp://10.10.10.21/var/www/webdav/12345.txt","STOR",     filePath);
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);` before attempting the upload

Comment: @AlexK. Now I'm getting a new exception "System Error"

Answer (score 0):

@Mainak, you need to provide a credential to the FTP server, so it can validate if you're allowed to access it. Try this:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
string filePath = "D:/CLIENT/12345.txt";
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpusername", "ftpuserpassword");
webClient.UploadFile("ftp://10.10.10.21/var/www/webdav/12345.txt","STOR",     filePath);
}
```